# Integrate the indefinite integral?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Integrate the indefinite integral ?

$$\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2} + \sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx$$

---

My try :-

Let $x^2 = t \to 2xdx=dt$ and then rationalize

I have,

$$\frac{1}{4a^2}\int \sqrt{t-a^2}- \sqrt{t+a^2}dt$$

---

I know its silly, but I don't know how to get further ?

Comment: I would multiply the given integral top and bottom with the denominator's conjugate. That way you can split the integral in two since the new denominator is only $-2a^2$

Comment: for your first integral se $$x=a\cosh(t)$$ and for the second one $$x=a\tan(t)$$

Comment: we have $$x^2-a^2-x^2-a^2=-2a^2$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example,
$$
\int(t-a^2)^{1/2}\,dt=\frac{2}{3}(t-a^2)^{3/2}+C
$$

Comment: Is there no need to go inside the square root after what you did and integrate ?

Comment: Jon, no because the Chain rule does not "do" anything here, derivative of $t-a^2$ with respect to $t$ is....

Comment: No, try to differentiate what I wrote.

Comment: Thanks @imranfat, fixed.

Comment: @mickep I don't know what was i thinking, but yeah it was silly, thanks :))

Answer (score 1):

Rationalizing yields $\int\frac{x\left(\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-\sqrt{x^2-a^2}\right)}{2a^2}$ using your substitution the integral becomes $\color{red}{\frac{1}{4a^2}}\displaystyle\int\sqrt{t+a^2}-\sqrt{t-a^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$. Because the derivative of $t+$ any constant is just $1$, we simply integrate, $\frac{1}{4a^2}\left(\frac{2}{3}(t+a^2)^{3/2}-\frac{2}{3}(t-a^2)^{3/2}\right)+C$ and then  substitute back $t=x^2$